# работа с random (30 обезьян)

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

как оптимизировать код - набор гласных/согласных и варианты слогов выглядят жутко (unpythonic at all)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def get_word():
    import random
    vowels_list = 'ааааееееёииииоооуыэюя'
    consonants_list = 'бббвввггддджзййккклллмммннннпппрррссстттффхцччшщ'

    def vowel():
        return random.choice(vowels_list)

    def consonant():
        return random.choice(consonants_list)

    type1 = vowel()
    type2 = consonant()
    type3 = vowel() + consonant()
    type4 = consonant() + vowel()
    type5 = vowel() + consonant() + vowel()
    type6 = consonant() + vowel() + consonant()
    type7 = vowel() + consonant() + vowel() + consonant()
    type8 = consonant() + vowel() + consonant() + vowel()
    type9 = consonant() + consonant() + vowel()
    types = [type1, type2, type3, type4, type5, type6, type7, type8, type9]

    return ''.join(random.sample(types, 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_of_words = 55
    for i in range(num_of_words):
        print(get_word())
```

Comment: полезно словами описывать, *что* код делает, даже если вы думаете, что *как* он это реализует является правильным. Характерные примеры ввода/вывода тоже не помешают.

Comment: этот код генерирует псевдорусские слова, комбинируя слоги (открытые, закрытие и т.п.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое явное, что видится, закодировать возможные типы в виде последовательностей из нулей и единиц (если у этих типов есть какакя-то системность, то можно еще сделать генерацию типов, а не явное их перечисление):

```
def get_word():
    import random
    vowels_list     = 'ааааееееёииииоооуыэюя'
    consonants_list = 'бббвввггддджзййккклллмммннннпппрррссстттффхцччшщ'

    def vowel():
        return random.choice(vowels_list)

    def consonant():
        return random.choice(consonants_list)

    codes = ['0', '1', '01', '10', '010', '101', '0101', '1010', '110']
    types = [
        ''.join(vowel() if c == '0' else consonant() for c in code)
        for code in codes]

    return ''.join(random.sample(types, 2))
```

---

**Обновление**

Насчет объединения `vowel` и `consonant`, первое, что приходит в голову, -- написать общую функцию выбора:

```
def get_word():
    import random
    vowels_list     = 'ааааееееёииииоооуыэюя'
    consonants_list = 'бббвввггддджзййккклллмммннннпппрррссстттффхцччшщ'

    def choose(letter_list):
        return random.choice(letter_list)

    codes = ['0', '1', '01', '10', '010', '101', '0101', '1010', '110']
    types = [
        ''.join(choose(vowels_list if c == '0' else consonants_list)
                for c in code)
        for code in codes]

    return ''.join(random.sample(types, 2))
```

Но я бы в этом плане пошел дальше и вынес в отдельную функцию не выбор буквы, а генерацию "типа"; такая декомпозиция видится мне более подходящей, так как вспомогательная функция решает более объемную задачу, тем самым разгружая основную, и поэтому уменьшая максимальную сложность:

```
def get_word():
    import random
    vowels_list     = 'ааааееееёииииоооуыэюя'
    consonants_list = 'бббвввггддджзййккклллмммннннпппрррссстттффхцччшщ'

    def gen_type(code):
        return ''.join(random.choice(vowels_list if c == '0' else consonants_list)
                       for c in code)

    codes = ['0', '1', '01', '10', '010', '101', '0101', '1010', '110']
    types = [gen_type(code) for code in codes]

    return ''.join(random.sample(types, 2))
```

Насчет коэффициентов использования гласных и согласных не совсем понял, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Системность последовательностей подбиралась эмпирическим путем. Спасибо, выглядит красиво) Теперь буду думать над коэффициентами использования гласных и согласных в  vowels_list  и consonants_list. Функции vowel и consonant тоже, думаю, можно как-то объеденить.